# How to bring Firefox icon on the dash in Debian?

Tags: firefox, debian, gnome, gnome3, dash

I have downloaded the latest version of Firefox. Everytime I want to browse the Internet, I have to go to the Firefox folder and double-click on Firefox there. When I search for the browser in Debian, there are no results. How do I put a Firefox icon on the dash?

The desktop environment installed is GNOME 3.

Comment: Debian by itself does not have a GUI or a dashboard. It depends on which desktop environment you have installed. Do you have Gnome 3 or KDE?

Comment: You probably should not have deleted your account if you wanted to get control of this question. If you register here and contact the team they can maybe re-associate the accounts.